# Norm Euclidean-problem by proof

Tags: functional-analysis

This is my first post. I am sorry but my English is not very good.
So, I have problem:

> Let $\,a,\,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Find $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$, such that:
>   $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \left\lVert x-a\right\rVert = 2 \left\lVert  x-b  \right\rVert \iff \left\lVert x-c\right\rVert =r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $c:=\dfrac{4b-a}{3}$ and let $r:=\dfrac{2}{3}\|a-b\|.$

Let me explain why: you want $c$ to be such that $\|x-a\|=2\|x-b\|$ if and only if $\|x-c\|=r,$ this is equivalent to $\|x-a\|^2=4\|x-b\|^2$ if and only if $\|x-c\|^2=r^2$ or equivalently $\|a\|^2-2x\cdot a=3\|x\|^2+4\|b\|^2-8x\cdot b$ if and only if $\|x\|^2+\|c\|^2-2x\cdot c=r^2$

or equivalently $\|x\|^2-2x\cdot\left[\dfrac{1}{3}(4b-a)\right]+\dfrac{4\|b\|^2-\|a\|^2}{3}=0$ if and only if $\|x\|^2-2x\cdot c+\|c\|^2-r^2=0$ so if we compare the two expressions we conjecture that $c=\dfrac{1}{3}(4b-a)$ and $r=\sqrt{\|c\|^2+\dfrac{\|a\|^2-4\|b\|^2}{3}}=\dfrac{2}{3}\|a-b\|$ do the job (if we assume, of course, that $a\neq b;$ if they are equal then there is no such pair $(c,r)$)